# Get JSON data from raw String/HTML

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiwebview, ios11

There is a div on UIWebView which is hidden and on DIV, there is some kind of string which also contains some JSON response as well.

```
NSString *response = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('response').textContent"];
```

There is JSON response start with the key "FinalizeResult"
and the response string is

```
response = Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse Object
 (
[jsonOptions:protected] => 0
[data:protected] => {"FinalizeResult":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseDescription":"Request processed successfully","UniqueID":"18278712782","version":"2.0","Account":"MyAcount","Amount":"102.000","ApprovalCode":"21782","Balance":"102.000","CardBrand":"Visa","CardNumber":"411111******1111","CardToken":"21212122121","Fees":"0","OrderID":"166221"}}
[callback:protected] => 
[encodingOptions:protected] => 15
[headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object
    (
        [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array
            (
                [no-cache] => 1
            )

        [cookies:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [headerNames:protected] => Array
            (
                [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                [date] => Date
                [content-type] => Content-Type
            )

        [headers:protected] => Array
            (
                [cache-control] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => no-cache
                    )

                [date] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Mon, 04 Dec 2017 10:30:52 GMT
                    )

                [content-type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => application/json
                    )

            )

        [cacheControl:protected] => Array
            (
            )
    )
)
```

How can we get this JSON response?

Comment: Json response start with FinalizeResult and is it till the end of string ??

Comment: As you can see, there is a lot more text in the string after that json (substring) completion.

Comment: [data:protected] => {"FinalizeResult":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseDescription":"Request processed successfully","UniqueID":"18278712782","version":"2.0","Account":"MyAcount","Amount":"102.000","ApprovalCode":"21782","Balance":"102.000","CardBrand":"Visa","CardNumber":"411111******1111","CardToken":"21212122121","Fees":"0","OrderID":"166221"}}    -> this is json response ??

Comment: And what you want from it?

Comment: Yes, Thats the json response but i have the full string which has some other text also. Not able to get the JSON array from response string.

Comment: I'm clearly not a JS developer, but maybe `document.getElementById('response').data` or `document.getElementById('response').data.textContent`? Seems more to be an JavaScript issue than a Objective-C, and you may so get better answers.